# Python poetry set up

Tags: python, python-poetry

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "webapp"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.4.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I have a pyproject.toml file. What would be the command line to change dependency versions? How do I add depdencies to .group.dev.depdencies only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use the `poetry add` and the package name and the desired version,and also to add dependencies to the `[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]` section, you can use the `--dev` flag!

something like this :

```
poetry add pytest@^8.0.0 --dev
```